# Nuget and conflicting dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, nuget, nancy

We are using Nuget to include a couple of dependencies in our project:

- Nancy 1.4.3
- Nancy.Authentication.Forms 1.4.1 (this itself has a dep.
  on Nancy >= 1.4.1)

This results in a build warning:

> Found conflicts between different versions of the same assembly...

Turning on diagnostic build output shows:

> There was a conflict between "Nancy, Version=1.4.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null" and "Nancy, Version=1.4.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null"...
>
> Nancy, Version=1.4.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" was
>   chosen because it was primary and "Nancy, Version=1.4.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" was not...

Our options are:

1) Downgrade to use Nancy 1.4.1

2) Use binding redirects to force use of the later version - this will get rid of the warning but is it sensible?

3) Something else?

What is the best way to resolve this?

As a side point, it appears that the Nancy 1.4.3 DLL downloaded by Nuget has File version 1.4.2.0 and Product version 1.4.3 (not sure this is correct).

**UPDATE:**
The warnings are resolved, however the real question is:

**Is it sensible to use binding redirects? Could this introduce bugs? Should we assume that any Nuget dependency is well-tested against *its dependencies* (minimum version and later versions)?**

Comment: In the project where Nancy.Authentication.Forms 1.4.1 is, explicitly reference Nancy 1.4.3 that should fix the issue.

Comment: @R.Rusev thanks but we already have that reference.

Comment: I just tested 2 project Project A with reference to Nancy.Authentication.Forms 1.4.1 and Project B with reference to Nancy 1.4.3.. Project B references Project A. After I upgraded the version of Project A to Nancy 1.4.3. there was no warning. So are you sure all projects are referencing the right version of Nancy?

Comment: @R.Rusev I just did the same, except I had both projects reference Nancy & Nancy.Authentication.Forms. This does not result in any warnings, but there are still conflict messages in diagnostic build output. It turns out that my build warnings were actually caused by conflicting Newtonsoft.Json references. I removed an unrelated reference from one of the projects and uninstalled the same dependency in Nuget package manager, this seemed to shock the package manager into also adding binding redirects for Newtonsoft.Json, which has resolved the warnings. But my original question still stands...